# Common root question on quadratics equations to show that $a+b+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, examples-counterexamples, quadratics

If $f(x)=ax^2+bx-c$ and $g(x)=ax^2+cx+b$ have a common root , show that $a+b+c=0$.

I tried this by thinking that $\alpha$ is the common root and then I got by substituting and solving ,

$(b^2+c^2)(b-c)+a(b+c)^2=0$

how can I proceed from here ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Note that $g(1)=0.$

Comment: @Angelo Mark You can not change the given after answer on your question. Ask new question.

Comment: i missed to mention that f is not identical to g. Really sorry. I'll mark your answer correct and ask this again, :D

Comment: Open new topic, please. Thank you!

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ and $g$ having a common root is that $a(b+c)^2+b(b^2-c^2)-c(b-c)^2=0$. In fact, a common root is a roots of $(f-g)(x)=(b-c)x-(b+c)$. The condition above is equivalent to this root being a root of $f$, but being also a root of $f-g$, it is equivalent to being a root of $g$ too. This condition is not equivalent to $a+b+c=0$, even when $b,c\neq 0$.

Comment: @Angelo Mark Open new topic. It's not fair that you are doing. By the way, you new problem is also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is WRONG.

Let $a=2,b=0,c=2$, then $f(x)=2x^2-2, g(x)=2x^2+2x$. It's clear that $-1$ is the common root, but $a+b+c=4\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong.

Try $b=c=0$ and $a=1$.

Comment: Thanks :)  BUT f is not equal to g

Comment: @Angelo Mark But $x^2$ and $x^2$ have common root. You can not change the given now. Ask another question.

Comment: Okay . Do not worry. I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks. And really sorry that I missed to mention that f and g are not identical

Comment: @Angelo Mark This happens. All correct.

Comment: Why someone down voted?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Vieta's formulas.

Let the roots of $f$ be $p$ and $q$. Let the roots of $g$ be $p$ and $r$.

Then $$p+q=-\frac ba,\quad pq=-\frac ca$$ and $$p+r=-\frac ca,\quad pr=\frac ba$$

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $a=c, b=0$. That is:
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx-c=ax^2-a=0 \Rightarrow x=\pm 1;\\
g(x)=ax^2+cx+b=ax^2+ax=0 \Rightarrow x=-1;0.$$

Backwards checking: if $c=-(a+b)$, then:
$$f(x)= ax^2+bx-c=0 \iff ax^2+bx+a+b=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) \\
g(x)=ax^2+cx+b=0 \iff ax^2-ax-bx+b=0 \iff (x-1)(ax+a-b)=0 \ \ \ \ (2) $$
Then, from $(2)$:
$$x-1=0 \stackrel{(1)}{\Rightarrow} a=-b.\\
ax+a-b=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{b-a}{a} \Rightarrow a\frac{(b-a)^2}{a^2}+b\frac{b-a}{a}+a+b=0 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=ab.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Analysis*:

If $f,g$ has one same root, then it is also a root of $f-g$. Since
$$
f(x) - g(x) = (b-c)x -(b+c), 
$$
then common root should be
$$
r = \frac {b+c} {b-c} \quad [b \neq c].
$$
Plug this into $f(x)$:
$$
a (b+c)^2 + b (b+c)(b-c) - c(b-c)^2 =0,
$$
which is
$$
a(b+c)^2 + b^3 -c^3 +bc^2 -cb^2 =0.
$$
Hence
$$
a + b + c = \frac 1 {(b+c)^2} (2c^3 + 4b^2c + 2bc^2) = \frac {2c} {(b+c)^2} (c^2 + 2b^2 + bc).
$$
If $c = 0$, and if $b\neq 0$, then $a+b  + c = 0$. If $c \neq 0$ and $b +c \neq 0$, then 
$$
|a +b +c| = \frac {2|c|} {(b+c)^2} \left( \left( c+\frac b2\right)^2 +\frac 74 b^2\right) > 0.
$$
Now a counterexample: take $b=0$, then $a = c $. Pick $a =c =1$, then
$$
f(x) = x^2 - 1= (x+1)(x-1),\quad g(x)= x^2+x =x(x+1),
$$
clearly they have a common root $-1$ but $a+b+c = g(1)=2\neq 0$.

**Conclusion: such claim fails.**

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the roots of $f$ are $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 + 4ac}}{2a}$. (Why? What happened to the minus sign in the quadratic formula?)

What are the roots of $g$?

Now suppose that the first root of $f$ equals the first root of $g$, and three other cases.

(Yes, that's a very pedestrian way to approach this problem, but it'll get you there.)

Comment: Tried this way , but its hard to get the answer

Comment: That's why it's an exercise. If it were easy, it'd just be a remark in the textbook. Why don't you show us your work on this approach (use the "edit" button below your question to fill in what you've done), and we can help you proceed. Yeah, it'll mean typing a lot of math...but that's what you're asking **us** to do, and *you're* the one getting the benefit, so perhaps you should be doing more of the work.

Comment: I did this whole day

Comment: Good for you. But **we** don't know what you've done, because you haven't bothered to show us. Sigh. We're *really* not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 2: An alternative approach is to say that

$$
f(x) = a (x - u) (x - v)
$$
for some numbers $u$ and $v$ (the roots of $f$), and 
$$
g(x) = a(x-u) (x - w)
$$

(the $u$ is repeated because $f$ and $g$ share a root; it's also *possible* that $v = w$, but not required by any means.)

Now if you expand out $f$, you'll find a relation between $b$ and $u, v$, and between $c$ and $u, v$; similarly for $g$. See where that leads you.

Comment: did it but leads to the same place where I got stuck

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx-c$$
$$g(x)=ax^2+cx+b$$
for f(x), the roots are given by:
$$(1)\,x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a} \text{and}\, x=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}$$
for g(x), the roots are given by:
$$(2)\,x=\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2-4ab}}{2a} \text{and}\,x=\frac{-c-\sqrt{c^2-4ab}}{2a}$$
since $2a$ is common on the bottom you could remove this then make the two sides equal to each other?

Answer (score 0):

> If $f(x)=ax^2+bx-c$ and $g(x)=ax^2+cx+b$ have a common root , show that $a+b+c=0$.

The statement is false, as pointed out in several answers already.

The problem most likely has a typo, however, and the following statement is in fact true:

> If $b \ne c$, then $f(x)=ax^2+bx \color{red}{+}c$ and $g(x)=ax^2+cx+b$ have a common root iff $a+b+c=0$.

The proof follows immediately by subtracting the two equations, which gives $\,(b-c)(x-1)=0\,$, therefore the common root must be $\,x=1\,$.